# CSS3 transition and DOM, weird behavior

Tags: css

**My problem is:** I need a way to catch the `aside` when `section:hover` and vice versa, or another (CSS) way for applying [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/jozvwcg4/) transition. I want the hovered element to go from current `width` to `100vw`, in the same time I want the other element's `width` to go to `0vw`, that should be happening in the particular time (2s here).

It's not a problem if there is a solution using another selector instead of `~` selector, or totally different way.

CSS:

```
aside, section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, display 2s; /* time updated */
    transition: width 2s, display 2s; /* time updated */
    background-color: red;
}

section {
    background-color:black;
}

section:hover, aside:hover {
    width: 100vw;
}

aside:hover ~ section /* work */  ,section:hover ~ aside /* invalid selector */ { 
    width: 0vw;                                                        
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <aside></aside>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

This is my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u6o7emfr/9/), and has a wrong floating issue (beside the second_element:hover selector issue).

<del>When I swap the HTML `<aside>` section, the behavior is swapping too, so the first DOM element's transition is going fine, but the second is not. Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/64nqc4n2/5/) after the swapping.</del>

Comment: What is the exact result you are looking for?

Comment: @ Maximillian I want the hovered element to go from current width->100vw, in the same time I want the other element width to go to 0vw, that should be happening in the particular time (2s here).

Comment: The sibling selectors in CSS work only on siblings that are below the current element in the DOM and so there is no pure CSS way to get this done as far as I am aware. It would work either for the `aside` or the `section` only depending on the order of elements.

Comment: @Harry I realize that and marked it as /* invalid selector */, it's not a problem if there is a solution using another selector instead of ~ selector, or totally different way.

Comment: @Amr: I have added a solution using a different method. It is not 100% as you wish but in my opinion this is the closest you can get to with pure CSS (and also have good browser support). I have also added the clarifications that you provided in comments into the question.

Comment: @Harry while there are two (CSS) good answers (yours, and red devil's one), yours have a small bug (white space appear when the move starts) but will work with older browsers, and devil's one works fine, but limited when it comes to IE8, it's little confusing to choose, so I'm just doing some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** This is at best an educated hack using absolute positioning and hidden overflows. I wouldn't generally recommend this approach for anybody but I am leaving this as an answer since you are intent on using a CSS only solution.

We can sort of achieve what you are looking for, by absolutely positioning the two elements and then adjusting their positioning attributes + `width` during hover. `overflow: hidden` on parent is important to the whole working of this approach.

This still isn't 100% perfect as you would see that hovering on the red block doesn't offset the black block but just seems to go over it unlike what happens when the black block is hovered. I don't think you can get it any closer without using scripting.

The advantage of this approach over any other possible ones is that this **should work even in older browsers** as we aren't really using any new properties.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section,
aside {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
section {
  right: 0%;
  background: red;
}
aside {
  right: 50%;
  background: black;
}
section:hover,
aside:hover {
  width: 100vw;
}
aside:hover {
  right: 0%;
}
aside:hover + section {
  right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside>Some lengthy content
    <br/>with line breaks.</aside>
  <section>Some lengthy content
    <br/>with line breaks.</section>
</body>
```

Comment: In Chrome 45 (I don't know about other browsers), small bug: white space (has inconstant width) appears for a moment (between the divs or in the left side), it's appear after hovering the aside until it goes 100% then and hover section while moving to its original position.
**it takes some tries to be detected.

Comment: about me: always seek the perfectness as possible, now it's perfect, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Right, and you got it

Answer (score 1):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
}


.Box {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}
.Box:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100vw;
}
.Box:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin);
}

.Section {
  background-color: red;  
}
.Section:hover {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.Section:after {
  content: '#Section';
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.Aside {
  background-color: black;  
}
.Aside:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.Aside:after {
  content: '#Aside';
  color: rgba(255,0,0,.8);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="Box Section"></section>
  <aside class="Box Aside"></aside>
</body>
```

But behavior of Aside is not similar as behavior of Section;

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
}


.Box {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}
.Box:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100vw;
}
.Box:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin);
}

.Section {
  background-color: red;
  order: 2;
}
.Section:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.Section:after {
  content: '#Section';
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.Section:hover ~ .Aside {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 2s ease-in 1s;
}

.Aside {
  background-color: black;
  order: 1;
}
.Aside:hover {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.Aside:after {
  content: '#Aside';
  color: rgba(255,0,0,.8);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="Box Section"></section>
  <aside class="Box Aside"></aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't working either - it's just pushing the black div to the bottom. You can't use a sibling selector after a CSS hover.

There's a couple ways you could solve this. Without rearranging your DOM, the most appropriate thing would probably be flexbox.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
aside, section{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width:50vw;
    -webkit-transition: all 10s linear;
    transition: all 10s linear;
    background-color:red;
}

aside:hover, section:hover {
   width: 100vw;
}

section {background-color:black;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6o7emfr/7/

Comment: A value of 100000% for any property is probably bad practice.

Comment: I know that it's not working, I put the samples to help in problem detection,  my goal is doing this via transition (time> 0s) in your example the transition isn't working (because it depends on hover), thank you.

Comment: @TylerH I'm aware of that, but unless you have a better solution?

Comment: @J4G the transition in your jsfiddle is different than mine, in yours the element going to 100vw in static time (not given time) and going back in the given time, I need it to go to 100vw in a given time (ex 10s), and go back to its original width in the particular time too.
*note: I'm a beginner in CSS3 transition.

Comment: @Amr Well I gave it one more shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is A jQuery Solution:

```js
$("aside").hover(function(){
   $(this).prev().css("width","0%");
}, function(){
   $(this).prev().css("width","50%");
});

$("section").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("width","100%");
}, function(){
   $(this).css("width","50%");
});
```

```css
section {
  background: red;  
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

aside {
  background: black; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section></section>
  <aside></aside>
</body>
```

Comment: If some day we could change the previous element or at least the parent element in CSS, this would be possible in PURE CSS.

Comment: My second_element:hover selector is wrong, I'm asking here to find a totally new way to do this, and I used your solution result to clarify my goal, I hope that it's okay.

Comment: Your selector is wrong because `~` is  for changing elements after the main selector. but aside is before section and you can't change it with css.